# First variable in Microsoft Word 2010 Equations not italicized

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, equations

When I insert an equation in Microsoft Word 2010 x64 (running on Windows 7 x64) and start adding text, the first variable is always unitalicized:

[image: Example equation from Microsoft Word with unitalicized first variable]

This means I have to manually italicize the first variable each time I create an equation. Anyone know how to get it to automatically italicize all of the text?